# FPDF Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (PHP)

Tags: php, fpdf

This is a often discussed issue but so far no solution seems to fit for my problem.
I'm generating a pdf with $pdf = new FPDF(); . This works fine. But now I want to have a footer with the page number. After trying a lot of things I found out, that if you want to set a footer, you need to create an instance with $pdf = new yourPDFclassName(); (which extends the parent FDF class).

Running the whole thing again I receive the error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes) in /..blabla/yourPDFclassName.php on line 16

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs when I call the child class? I mean it works with the parent class... And btw, 77 bytes are much smaller than the 33554432 bytes ... hmm

```
class REPORTSPDF extends FPDF { .... }

16: $pdf = new REPORTSPDF();
```

The line 16 is in the constructor of REPORTSPDF. There are no other lines before line 16. It just crashes when $pdf = new REPORTSPDF() is called.

Without the Footer function I have the same error. The weird thing is that when I change line 16 to

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
```

everything works fine (with the exception that I don't have a footer).

Comment: could you please post your code (especialy the first 16 lines to where the problem happens?)? do you have any loops in you pdf that could cause the problem or doesn't even a simple hello-world work? does your own class work if you leave the footer out?

Comment: I updated the information in my first post.

Comment: Adding the footer will obviously consume more memory, as the whole thing has to be kept in memory. That's why you don't go over the memory limit when you don't add the footer. [edit] wait, if line 16 is in the constructor of REPORTSPDF, and it creates an instance of REPORTSPDF, wouldn't that end up in a loop?

Comment: @Andrei - suspect your reference to the loop is the crux of the problem, surely the code should simply call parent::__construct() and use $this references

Comment: @Mark - indeed, sorry ... thought it was clear enough.

Comment: also need to call parent::_construct() to get some definitions of the parent class.

Comment: @Andrei - It was a good hint for an experienced OOP coder, but not (perhaps) for somebody less familiar with PHP's OOP... if you'd put it as an answer I'd have upvoted you: as it is, all I could do was mark up your comment

Comment: @mkn: from your comment to my answer i nuderstood that solved your problem. if so, please mark it (or another one that helped you to find your problem) as answer by klicking on the gray checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: sorry for not marking the question as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like you have an infinite loop in you code. try to do a simple hello-world-test ans see what happens and check all loop in your code.

Comment: it does have a loop in the constructor... thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

### Increase memory limit

There are 3 ways to increase memory limit

- **using config file**

  Change memory limit in php.ini

  memory_limit = 32M
- **using PHP**

  ini_set('memory_limit','32M');
- **using htaccess**

  php_value memory_limit 32M

### Methods in different server

**Shared Hosting**

```
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

**Dedicated or VPS Optimized**

```
ssh -lroot domain.com

locate php.ini

vi /usr/local/php/etc/php.ini

edit to 

memory_limit=32M;

save file

httpd restart

/sbin/service httpd restart
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to eliminate the problem than to work around it? generating a pdf shouldn't use !32MB! ram

Comment: @oezi that right the more is better, i consider if its shared server then 16m is even good.

Answer (score 3):

The error message means that, while attempting to allocate an *additional* 77 bytes, the memory limit of 33554432 bytes was exceeded.

There are only two ways around this: either optimize the code in your subclass so you don't need as much memory, or increase your memory limit in php.ini (or using equivalent methods for manipulating with the PHP configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Change your memory_limit.

try,

```
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

Comment: as said to japanpro: wouldn't it be better to eliminate the problem than to work around it? generating a pdf shouldn't use !32MB! ram

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it myself, but the [FPDF2File](http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/76/) extension to FPDF is an attempt to build the PDF page by page to disk rather than purely in memory