# FPDF runs into exhausted memory, but more than enough is allocated

Tags: php, .htaccess, memory, fpdf, ini

I'm using the fpdf-lib in order to create pdfs, which are sent by email.
In my php error-log files I checked that one pdf couldn't be generated, because the allowed memory size exhausted.

The line says the following:

```
Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5247681 bytes) in /htdocs/app/resources/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1378
```

What I don't get is the following:

- my managed web server serves 4GB of RAM
- I've allocated with the `php.ini` file AND `.htaccess` more than 2048MB (checked with `phpinfo();`
- the lines says that the memory limit is 16777216 bytes (16MB), and fpdf wanted to allocate 5247681 bytes (5MB), what is less then the memory limit of 16MB (but actually I have 2GB RAM)?

Do I miss something?

Comment: Check this SO thread. It may help. Specialy accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804315/fpdf-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-php